# How to show the grid for storyboard view/edit in Xcode 5?

Tags: ios7, xcode5

I just downloaded Xcode 5 and found the grid is gone? Did a quick search on web but did not find answers. Is there a way to turn it on? Thanks!

Added screenshot according to Tommie

[image]

Comment: I've provided the answer below. Please review and let me know if you have further information on this matter. Also if you find the answer acceptable please click the checkmark. This action will help others understand the issue is closed and encourage future responses to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this is not possible. I have submitted a bug report on this item: 15176329. In general the existing options to change viewable environment of a nib or storyboard are located in Editor > Canvas.

One exception is when you are in a data model at which point one can navigate to Editor > Canvas and choose either Show Grid or Hide Grid to effect the view of that environment.

Hope this answers your question sufficiently. Apple may add this back in future versions of the OS if enough folks file duplicate bug reports.

Comment: Did not see the Show?Hide Grid in Editor > Canvas

Comment: @marsant - The Show/Hide Grid is ONLY available when you select a data model file first. It is not available in storyboards, which is why my answer to your question is that it is not currently possible.